# bitwise operations in C receiving binary in a char

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I am receiving 2 bytes of binary information via Serial in C.

I am receiving them in a char.

So I need to join the 2 chars to make a int but Im unsure how to do that.. first of all the first byte is in binary format and not char format.. So im unsure how I Can convert it into a useable form for my program.

Comment: Is the most-significant byte first or second?

Comment: convert each char into an int, bit shift the upper byte and add them together

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just `OR` them together ?

```
x = (b1 << 8) | b2;
```

Make sure they're unsigned or cast accordingly (shifting signed stuff is nasty).

Comment: @asaelr It will be promoted to a higher type.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
int my_int=char1;
myint<<=8;
myint|=char2;
```

This assumes `char1` contains the most significant byte. Switch the 1 and 2 otherwise.

Comment: This also assumes char is unsigned.

Answer (score 1):

use `unsigned char` to avoid sign-extension problems.

```
val16 = char1 * 256 + char2;
```

Answer (score 1):

For a start, it would be better to receive them in an *unsigned* char just so you have no issues with sign extension and the like.

If you want to combine them, you can use something like:

```
int val = ch1; val = val << 8 | ch2;
```

or:

```
int val = ch2; val = val << 8 | ch1;
```

depending on the endian-ness of your system, and assuming your system has an eight-bit `char` type.

Answer (score 0):

if MSB (Most Significant Byte) comes first:

```
unsigned char array[2];
...
int bla;
bla = array[1] | (array[0] << 8);
```

if LSB (Least Significant Byte) comes first:

```
bla = array[0] | (array[1] << 8);
```